# $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N=Aut(N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N$ be a normal abelain subgroup of $G$ such that $N=C_G(N)$ and $G/N\cong Aut(N)$. Can we say that $G$ is a semidirect product of $N$ and $Aut(N)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be an elementary abelian $2$-group of order $2^k$, where $k=3,4$ or $5$. Then there are nonsplit extensions of $N$ by ${\rm Aut}(N) \cong {\rm GL}(k,2)$. So the answer is no. These are the only counterexamples when $N$ is elementary abelian. I am not sure what happens for other abelian groups $N$.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is false.

Consider the group $Q_8$, generated by the elements $i$, $j$, $k$.

It has all subgroups cyclic and normal and is not isomorphic to any semidirect product of groups.

Consider $N$ as the subgroup generated by $i$, that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ because it is cyclic.

Obviousely $N \subseteq C_G(N)$, but the center of $Q_8$ is  $\{1, -1\}$, so must be $N=C_G(N)$.

Now you obtain a counterexample, because $Q_8/N \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\simeq Aut(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$.